# How to access to symfony Dev environnement behind varnish?

Tags: symfony, varnish, apache2.4

After installing varnish in front of apache2, I can not access the dev environment of symfony2 project (connected from localhost, so it worked before installing varnish).

I got the symfony2 access denied message "You are not allowed to access this file. Check app_dev.php for more information."

When looking into app_dev.php file:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])
    || isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])
    || !(in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array('127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1')) || php_sapi_name() === 'cli-server')
) {
    header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
    exit('You are not allowed to access this file. Check '.basename(__FILE__).' for more information.');
}
```

After debuging the problem, i found that the **$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'] is NULL.**

How to fix this ?

Thank you.

---

Note: I'm using ubuntu 14.04 + apache2.4 + varnish 3 + Symfony2.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line would return a 403 if either:

- HTTP_CLIENT_IP header is present
- HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header is present
- $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is not one of '127.0.0.1', 'fe80::1', '::1'

Probably you are setting the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header in varnish, or varnish is setting it for you, depending on the varnish version. Unset it or rewrite the condition, it's a safety measure so act accordingly.

You have some interesting info here: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/cache/varnish.html

Comment: Varnish sets the "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR", so i edited the app_dev file and now it works.